# how to make offline android app that saves data on sqlite and send data to mysql when there is internet automatically

Tags: android

I am working on android application that register members, save 50 records to a local database then transfer the records to mysql database on the server and delete the records on the local database for another batch of registration.
Specific problems.

(1)how to get camera image from imageView save it to sqlite?
(2)how to make my editText a date picker for date of birth and save it to sqlite?
(3)how to sense internet connection and transfer sqlite data to mysql when records reach 50?
(4)how to delete sqlite data when successfully transferred to mysql?

Below is my Activity for the registration
        package com.example.administrator.user_enrollment;

```
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
private EditText editText1;
private EditText editText2;
private EditText editText3;
private EditText editText4;
private EditText editText5;
private EditText editText6;
private EditText editText7;
private EditText editText8;
private EditText editText9;
private EditText editText10;
private EditText editText11;
private Button button1;
private Button button2;
private Button button3;
private RadioGroup radioDisability;
private RadioButton radioYes;
private RadioButton radioNo;
private RadioGroup radioGender;
private RadioButton radioMale;
private RadioButton radioFemale;
private Spinner spinner1;
private Spinner spinner2;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private ImageView picture;
  String fitness;
  String gender;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.reg);

    createDatabase();

    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    editText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    editText5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    editText6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    editText7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
    editText8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText8);
    editText9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText9);
    editText10 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText10);
    editText11 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText11);
    radioDisability = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioDisability);
    radioNo = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioNo);
    radioYes = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioYes);
    radioGender = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGender);
    radioMale = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioMale);
    radioFemale = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioFemale);
    picture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture) ;
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    button3.setOnClickListener(this);



}

public void takeImageFromCamera(View view) {
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap mphoto = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        picture.setImageBitmap(mphoto);
    }
}

protected void createDatabase(){
    db=openOrCreateDatabase("aecdporg_new", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bio(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, f_name VARCHAR,m_name VARCHAR,l_name VARCHAR,dob DATE,fitness VARCHAR,occupation VARCHAR,religion VARCHAR,gender VARCHAR,phone VARCHAR,status VARCHAR,hhname VARCHAR,ward VARCHAR,village VARCHAR,district VARCHAR,lga VARCHAR");
    }
protected void insertIntoDB() {
    String f_name = editText1.getText().toString().trim();
    String m_name = editText2.getText().toString().trim();
    String l_name = editText3.getText().toString().trim();
    String dob = editText4.getText().toString().trim();

    int selectedId = radioDisability.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    radioNo = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
    radioYes = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
    if (selectedId == radioNo.getId()) {

         fitness = "Not fit";
    }
    else
    {
            fitness = "fit";
    }


    String religion = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
    String occupation = editText5.getText().toString().trim();
    int selectedId2 = radioGender.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    radioMale = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId2);
    radioFemale = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId2);
    if(selectedId2== radioMale.getId()){
        gender ="Male";
    }
    else
    {
        gender = "Female";
    }

    String phone = editText6.getText().toString().trim();
    String status = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
    String household_name = editText7.getText().toString().trim();
    String lga = editText7.getText().toString().trim();
    String district = editText8.getText().toString().trim();
    String village = editText9.getText().toString().trim();
    String ward = editText10.getText().toString().trim();
    String photo = editText1.getText().toString().trim();

    if(f_name.equals("") || l_name.equals("") || dob.equals("") || fitness.equals("") || religion.equals("") || occupation.equals("") || gender.equals("") || phone.equals("") || status.equals("") || household_name.equals("")|| lga.equals("") || district.equals("") || village.equals("") || ward.equals("") || photo.equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please fill all fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
        }

    String query = "INSERT INTO bio (f_name,m_name,l_name,dob,fitness,religion,occupation,gender,phone,status,hhname,lga,district,village,ward,photo) VALUES('"+f_name+"', '"+m_name+"', '"+l_name+"', '"+dob+"', '"+fitness+"', '"+religion+"','"+occupation+"', '"+gender+"', '"+phone+"', '"+status+"','"+household_name+"', '"+dob+"', '"+lga+"', ''"+district+"', '"+village+"', '"+ward+"', '"+photo+"');";
    db.execSQL(query);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Saved Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu_main; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
    }
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
        }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == button2){
        insertIntoDB();
        }
    else if (v == button1){
        takeImageFromCamera(picture);
    }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a BroadcastReciever that check whether you are connected to internet or not.
For checking your internet connection you can use `ConnectivityManager`.
public boolean isInternetConnected() {

```
    ConnectivityManager cManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context
            .CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (cManager != null) {

        NetworkInfo networkInfos = cManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfos != null) {

            if(networkInfos.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){
                // Wifi Connected
            }
            else if(networkInfos.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
            {
                // Mobile Internet connected
            }
            return true;

        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Ans 1: For saving Image file in SQLite, you should convert `bitmap` in `byte[]` and then save it to database.

Ans 2: You can show a `DatePickerDialog` on `TextView OnClickListner` and get returned value in String and store in database.

Ans 3: You can add boundation when specific number of entries entered in database. You can bound user to have Internet connection when entry reaches to 50.

Ans 4: Also add a `boolean` in your database that will be true when data is *synchronized* and false when is not *synchronized*, according to your need. Then delete synchronized data from your table.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can convert your bitmap into byte[] array(Blob) and store in sqlite. Search for bitmap to byte[] conversion.

2) Override your edittext's touch and write function to show date picker . Selected date from picker can either formatted and save as string to database or you can store as timestamp value.

3) Write a check when ever you insert register data into database whether record count reached 50 . If yes, then check for internet connection and send data to server. Also keep a table in your database to keep value whether each 50 set data to uploaded or not. Check this table on any frequency and resend data if not send.

4) On success of upload delete your database records. You can use the data from the table mentioned in (3) to delete particular records from table. Keep range of id's in that table , like 1st and 50th item id.